# spring boot project as dependency inside another spring-boot project

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3

I have a spring boot project(project-lib) which I am including as maven dependency in another spring boot project(my-project).

now the project-lib uses logback and i want to exclude the logback dependency in my-project.

Also currently project-lib is defined as dependency with classifier `jar-with-dependencies`

Is it possible to define project-lib as normal dependency instead of jar-with-dependencies.

I tried to define it as normal dependency assuming it will download all the required dependencies as project-lib/pom.xml has already defined the required dependencies to run project-lib but it did not work that way.

part of pom.xml of my-project

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xyz/groupId>
            <artifactId>project-lib</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
        </dependency>
```